# Как изменить кодировку сайта

Tags: html, css, utf-8, перекодировка, cp1251

Как перевести сайт с UTF8 на windows-1251?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251"> в head

Comment: а ещё странички пересохранить

Comment: http://prntscr.com/qrcsdw вот у меня вот так получилось( Что нужно сделать, чтобы такого не было?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зависит от того, как сделан ваш сайт.

Если это чистый HTML + CSS, то будет достаточно добавить в

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

Заменить в самих файлах кодировку на указанную (например через notepad++) и залить это всё на хостинг.

*(на скриншоте пример перевода в UTF-8, нужная вам кодировка во вкладке "кодировки" - кириллица)*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же сайт на php - то всё сложнее. Нужно настроить правильное декодирование из базы данных или менять кодировку ещё и там. Опять же кодировка файлов, заголовков.

К тому же не ясно зачем вам из UTF-8 делать cp1251? В современных реалиях все наоборот стараются "переехать" на UTF8 т.к. он открывает массу возможностей, совместим со всем на свете и исключительно популярен.

Если у вас какие-то проблемы с выводом данных, то я бы рекомендовал найти и исправить их причины, а не менять кодировку ресурса.

Comment: Спасибо! Клиент просит сделать так, а зачем ему нужно - непонятно. Говорит надо и все. Я просто так и сделала через блокнот и получилось так prntscr.com/qrcsdw но это на локалке. У меня там html,css, js

Comment: @Katya Отлично. Если ответ был полезен - выберите его как решение и поднимите "вверх" (я тут ради репутации для портфолио). Будут вопросы - обращайтесь (в профиле есть контакты). Успехов!